# Input for create or update policy is not in proper format (.json Template in PowerShell-Script)

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-rm-template

I'm trying to deploy a resource group from a powershell script. The script gets the parameters etc. from a .json template.

For another resource group it worked fine (I just had to insert the "adminPassword" parameter), but now I have another resoruce group, which I can't redeploy from this script. First I thougt I just have to add the parameter before, but this template has a different structure, etc. So that means that I cannot find the place to insert the parameter.

But this isn't the problem. When I run the script, I'm getting the following error:

```
New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment : 08:35:01 - Resource Microsoft.RecoveryServices/vaults/backupPolicies 'alp-prd-core-rsvault1/DefaultPolicy' failed with message '{
  "error": {
    "code": "BMSUserErrorInvalidPolicyInput",
    "message": "Input for create or update policy is not in proper format\r\nPlease check format of parameters like schedule time, schedule days, retention time and retention days ",
    "target": null,
    "details": null,
    "innerError": null
```

(Sorry for bad format)

I looked in the template and one of the parameter the powershell doesn't like is the following:

```
"backupPolicies_DefaultPolicy_name": {
      "type": "String",
      "defaultValue": "DefaultPolicy"
    },
```

It's like the documentation from Microsoft (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-template-deploy)

So for that I don't know why this doesn't work, for the other Resource Group with their template it worked.

I hope you understand my issue.

Thanks in advance!

P.S. Template: `{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "virtualNetworks_alp_prd_core_vnet1_name": {
            "defaultValue": "alp-prd-core-vnet1",
            "type": "String"
        },
        "vaults_alp_prd_core_rsvault1_name": {
            "defaultValue": "alp-prd-core-rsvault1",
            "type": "String"
        },
        "subnets_internal_name": {
            "defaultValue": "internal",
            "type": "String"
        },
        "backupPolicies_DefaultPolicy_name": {
            "defaultValue": "DefaultPolicy",
            "type": "String"
        },
        "backupPolicies_HourlyLogBackup_name": {
            "defaultValue": "HourlyLogBackup",
            "type": "String"
        },
        "backupPolicies_%name%_Backup_Policy_name": {
            "defaultValue": "%name%-Backup-Policy",
            "type": "String"
        },
        "replicationAlertSettings_defaultAlertSetting_name": {
            "defaultValue": "defaultAlertSetting",
            "type": "String"
        },
        "virtualNetworkPeerings_alp_prd_core_vnet1_Net_Sync_name": {
            "defaultValue": "alp-prd-core-vnet1-Net-Sync",
            "type": "String"
        },
        "virtualNetworks_alp_prd_core_vnet1_id": {
            "defaultValue": "/subscriptions/%subsciptionID%/resourceGroups/NemetschekgroupAD/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/Net-Sync",
            "type": "String"
        },
        "virtualNetworkPeerings_alp_prd_core_vnet1_Net_Sync_id": {
          "defaultValue": "/subscriptions/%subsciptionID%/resourceGroups/NemetschekgroupAD/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/Net-Sync",
          "type": "String"
      }
    },
    "variables": {},
    "resources": [
      {
        "comments": "Generalized from resource: '/subscriptions/%subsciptionID%/resourceGroups/alp-prd-core-rg/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/alp-prd-core-vnet1'.",
        "type": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks",
        "name": "[parameters('virtualNetworks_alp_prd_core_vnet1_name')]",
        "apiVersion": "2018-02-01",
        "location": "westeurope",
        "scale": null,
        "properties": {
          "provisioningState": "Succeeded",
          "resourceGuid": "940c1d33-bbf4-4b01-a331-8096e8066a0a",
          "addressSpace": {
            "addressPrefixes": [
              "10.11.0.112/28"
            ]
          },
          "subnets": [
            {
              "name": "internal",
              "etag": "W/\"b5fce13f-36b0-4d55-aa19-755a78b696f2\"",
              "properties": {
                "provisioningState": "Succeeded",
                "addressPrefix": "10.11.0.112/28"
              }
            }
          ],
          "virtualNetworkPeerings": [
            {
              "name": "[concat(parameters('virtualNetworks_alp_prd_core_vnet1_name'),'-Net-Sync')]",
              "etag": "W/\"b5fce13f-36b0-4d55-aa19-755a78b696f2\"",
              "properties": {
                "provisioningState": "Succeeded",
                "peeringState": "Connected",
                "remoteVirtualNetwork": {
                  "id": "[parameters('virtualNetworks_alp_prd_core_vnet1_id')]"
                },
                "allowVirtualNetworkAccess": true,
                "allowForwardedTraffic": false,
                "allowGatewayTransit": false,
                "useRemoteGateways": true,
                "remoteAddressSpace": {
                  "addressPrefixes": [
                    "10.11.0.0/28",
                    "10.11.0.16/28"
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          ],
          "enableDdosProtection": false,
          "enableVmProtection": false
        },
        "dependsOn": []
      },
      {
        "comments": "Generalized from resource: '/subscriptions/%subsciptionID%/resourceGroups/alp-prd-core-rg/providers/Microsoft.RecoveryServices/vaults/alp-prd-core-rsvault1'.",
        "type": "Microsoft.RecoveryServices/vaults",
        "sku": {
          "name": "RS0",
          "tier": "Standard"
        },
        "name": "[parameters('vaults_alp_prd_core_rsvault1_name')]",
        "apiVersion": "2018-01-10",
        "location": "westeurope",
        "scale": null,
        "properties": {},
        "dependsOn": []
      },
        {
            "comments": "Generalized from resource: '/subscriptions/%subsciptionID%/resourceGroups/alp-prd-core-rg/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/alp-prd-core-vnet1/subnets/internal'.",
            "type": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets",
            "name": "[concat(parameters('virtualNetworks_alp_prd_core_vnet1_name'), '/', parameters('subnets_internal_name'))]",
            "apiVersion": "2018-02-01",
            "scale": null,
            "properties": {
                "provisioningState": "Succeeded",
                "addressPrefix": "10.11.0.112/28"
            },
            "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks', parameters('virtualNetworks_alp_prd_core_vnet1_name'))]"
            ]
        },
      {
        "comments": "Generalized from resource: '/subscriptions/%subsciptionID%/resourceGroups/alp-prd-core-rg/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/alp-prd-core-vnet1/virtualNetworkPeerings/alp-prd-core-vnet1-Net-Sync'.",
        "type": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/virtualNetworkPeerings",
        "name": "[concat(parameters('virtualNetworks_alp_prd_core_vnet1_name'), '/', parameters('virtualNetworkPeerings_alp_prd_core_vnet1_Net_Sync_name'))]",
        "apiVersion": "2018-02-01",
        "scale": null,
        "properties": {
          "provisioningState": "Succeeded",
          "peeringState": "Connected",
          "remoteVirtualNetwork": {
            "id": "[parameters('virtualNetworkPeerings_alp_prd_core_vnet1_Net_Sync_id')]"
          },
          "allowVirtualNetworkAccess": true,
          "allowForwardedTraffic": false,
          "allowGatewayTransit": false,
          "useRemoteGateways": true,
          "remoteAddressSpace": {
            "addressPrefixes": [
              "10.11.0.0/28",
              "10.11.0.16/28"
            ]
          }
        },
        "dependsOn": [
          "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks', parameters('virtualNetworks_alp_prd_core_vnet1_name'))]"
        ]
      },
      {
        "comments": "Generalized from resource: '/subscriptions/%subsciptionID%/resourcegroups/alp-prd-core-rg/providers/Microsoft.RecoveryServices/vaults/alp-prd-core-rsvault1/backupPolicies/%name%-Backup-Policy'.",
        "type": "Microsoft.RecoveryServices/vaults/backupPolicies",
        "name": "[concat(parameters('vaults_alp_prd_core_rsvault1_name'), '/', parameters('backupPolicies_%name%_Backup_Policy_name'))]",
        "apiVersion": "2016-12-01",
        "scale": null,
        "properties": {
          "backupManagementType": "AzureIaasVM",
          "protectedItemsCount": 0
        },
        "dependsOn": [
          "[resourceId('Microsoft.RecoveryServices/vaults', parameters('vaults_alp_prd_core_rsvault1_name'))]"
        ]
      },
      {
        "comments": "Generalized from resource: '/subscriptions/%subsciptionID%/resourcegroups/alp-prd-core-rg/providers/Microsoft.RecoveryServices/vaults/alp-prd-core-rsvault1/backupPolicies/HourlyLogBackup'.",
        "type": "Microsoft.RecoveryServices/vaults/backupPolicies",
        "name": "[concat(parameters('vaults_alp_prd_core_rsvault1_name'), '/', parameters('backupPolicies_HourlyLogBackup_name'))]",
        "apiVersion": "2016-12-01",
        "scale": null,
        "properties": {
          "backupManagementType": "AzureWorkload",
          "protectedItemsCount": 0
        },
        "dependsOn": [
          "[resourceId('Microsoft.RecoveryServices/vaults', parameters('vaults_alp_prd_core_rsvault1_name'))]"
        ]
      },
      {
        "comments": "Generalized from resource: '/subscriptions/%subsciptionID%/resourcegroups/alp-prd-core-rg/providers/Microsoft.RecoveryServices/vaults/alp-prd-core-rsvault1/backupPolicies/DefaultPolicy'.",
        "type": "Microsoft.RecoveryServices/vaults/backupPolicies",
        "name": "[concat(parameters('vaults_alp_prd_core_rsvault1_name'), '/', parameters('backupPolicies_DefaultPolicy_name'))]",
        "apiVersion": "2016-12-01",
        "scale": null,
        "properties": {
          "backupManagementType": "AzureIaasVM",
          "protectedItemsCount": 0
        },
        "dependsOn": [
          "[resourceId('Microsoft.RecoveryServices/vaults', parameters('vaults_alp_prd_core_rsvault1_name'))]"
        ]
      },
      {
        "comments": "Generalized from resource: '/Subscriptions/%subsciptionID%/resourceGroups/alp-prd-core-rg/providers/Microsoft.RecoveryServices/vaults/alp-prd-core-rsvault1/replicationAlertSettings/defaultAlertSetting'.",
        "type": "Microsoft.RecoveryServices/vaults/replicationAlertSettings",
        "name": "[concat(parameters('vaults_alp_prd_core_rsvault1_name'), '/', parameters('replicationAlertSettings_defaultAlertSetting_name'))]",
        "apiVersion": "2018-01-10",
        "scale": null,
        "properties": {
          "sendToOwners": "DoNotSend",
          "customEmailAddresses": [],
          "locale": ""
        },
        "dependsOn": [
          "[resourceId('Microsoft.RecoveryServices/vaults', parameters('vaults_alp_prd_core_rsvault1_name'))]"
        ]
      }
    ]
}`

Comment: The thing with ARM deployments is that it is completely dependant on your template itself, whether the deployment fails or not. That being said, if your another deployment succeeded it doesn't pretty much mean anything since you used a different template - If I understood correctly. It seems that you are deploying a recovery services vault. Have you included some backup policies already in the template? It would help dearly if you could provide either the whole template or at least the recovery services vault part of it. I've done a similar deployment just a couple of weeks ago without issue.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I added the whole template to my question. Please note that i replaced sensitive information e.g. Subscription ID or names as "%%".

Answer (score 0):

To me it seems like your template is missing the actual schedule, required for a successfuly backup policy deployment. I realize that you have exported the template from an existing deployment, but for some reason the policy itself is included, without the actual schedule (meaning when to back up virtual machines). Not sure why it is not included in the exported template.

I suggest you take an existing template - for example this https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/master/101-recovery-services-daily-backup-policy-create/azuredeploy.json as a baseline and edit your existing template to include all the necessary properties. Use that template as a reference, and you should end up with a working template.